# Php file not working when directed from html file

Tags: php

I have two files `first.html` and `first.php`

When I am running a php file alone my php file is working fine,but when I am trying to  direct that php file from my html file it is not working, it is showing nothing.

I am using xampp

Comment: And how do you direct it ? Show your codes maybe ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what do you mean? php file included properly in php file and not included in html file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code can't write in first.html. you are write PHP code in first.html than this data not display on browser.

=> first.html

```
<h1> html data </h1>
<?php echo "php data"; ?>

=> OUTPUT
    html data
```

=> first.php

```
<h1> html data </h1>
<?php echo "php data"; ?>

=> OUTPUT
   html data
   php data
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't run a **PHP File** from an **HTML File** but you can write some **HTML code** into a **PHP File** and include it in another **PHP File**

**Example :**

***htmlcontentfile.php***

```
<html>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</html>
```

***phpfile.php***

```
<?php
    include('htmlcontentfile.php');
?>
```

And you can mix two :

***otherfile.php***

```
<html>
 <h1>HTML Code example</h1>
 <p>Some text</p>
 <?php include('phpfile.php'); ?>
</html>
```

But **you can't include PHP file** in a file **without the .php extension**